# Loading unstructured text data in .txt Format to Python and create a Dataframe from it with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to load **unstructured text data .txt** representing job ads to **Python** with the help of **Pandas** and create a Dataframe from it. I am quite new to Python and have trouble getting started.

My data consists of many job advertisements with a specific ID (consisting of a combination of 14 Numbers) and I would like to store the Job ID and then the Text belonging to it in a dataframe for starters. Optimally Dataframe before cleaning would look like this:

**JOB ID**
12341234123412

**JOB DESCRIPTION**

[job description line in lists.... ]

The Code I tried but does not work is this:

```
    JobData = pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\JobMarketData.txt", sep ="/t") 
  print(JobData)
```

It gives me the **following errors**:

*Desktop/Spyder_following natural language processing.py:1: ParserWarning: Falling back to the* *'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and* *different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying* *engine='python'.*
*File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f*
*return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)*
*File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 463, in _read*
*data = parser.read(nrows)*

- File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1154, in read*
  *ret = self._engine.read(nrows)*
  *File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2493, in read*
- alldata = self._rows_to_cols(content)*
  *File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 3157, in* *_rows_to_cols*
- self._alert_malformed(msg, row_num + 1)*
- File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2914, in* *_alert_malformed*
- raise ParserError(msg)*
  *ParserError: Expected 1 fields in line 160538, saw 2. Error could possibly be due to quotes being* *ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.*

So far I only managed with the readlines function to read the .txt file into my Console

```
filename: 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\JobMarketData.txt'
with open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\JobMarketData.txt', encoding="utf8") as fn:
    ln=fn.readline()
    lncnt=1
    while ln:
        print("Line{}:{}".format(lncnt, ln.strip()))
        ln = fn.readline()
        lncnt += 1
```

But I don't know how I could continue with just the lines.
**Any help would be super appreciated!**

**The Data looks like this:**

12341234123412

Senior IT Specialist - NY

To enhance our IT operation in NY, we are looking for English-speaking IT Specialists to use their experience, existing business relationships and network of contacts .....

An in-depth knowledge of IT products is essential, as well as the ability to analyse and satisfy client requirements, while simultaneously fulfilling the aims of the Company with respect to , profitability.

Interested applicants should enjoy working in a dynamic team environment, contributing ideas and sharing the benefits of their experience, as well as participating in marketing activities.

Qualifications:
English mother-tongue - knowledge of German and other languages would be advantageous;
several years' experience in an English-speaking IT Environment
exhaustive knowledge of IT instruments

Comment: `df=pd.read_csv('data.txt',sep='/t',engine='python')`
if still have error, use different separator eg . tab (4x space)

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me this hint, it sent me on the right path =) In the end sep='\n', specifying header= None and squeeze = True worked for me!